# Why isnt my module always printing the lowest of 3 single inputs?

Tags: input, integer, compare

I am trying to get it to print the lowest of the 3 inputs but it is sometimes printing the second lowest.

```
a = (input())
b = (input())
c = (input())
if int(c) < int(b) and int(a):
  print (c)
elif int(b) < int(c) and int(a):
  print(b)
elif int(a) < int(b) and int(c):
  print (a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<`-operator is not distributed over fields connected with `and`. You need to check it explicitly.

```
a = (input())
b = (input())
c = (input())
if int(c) < int(b) and int(c) < int(a):
  print (c)
elif int(b) < int(a):
  print(b)
else:
  print (a)
```